# Jest functions chained onto expect() are not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I am having an issue in my Node.js backend related to testing. When I try to chain a function onto `.expect()`, such as `.toBeTruthy()` or `.toBe()`, I get an error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _supertest.default)(...).post(...).send(...).expect(...).expect(...).expect(...).toBeTruthy is not a function

      45 |
      46 |         return _bcrypt.default.compare(user.password, res.body.password);
    > 47 |       }).toBeTruthy();
         |          ^
      48 |     }); // test("New user should be able to login after registration", async () => {
      49 |     //    console.log("Login Test");
      50 |     //    return await request(app)

      at Object.<anonymous> (routes/tests/user.test.js:47:10)
```

Without the extra function at the end, the chain works.

In the `jest.config.js` file I have the root set to my `./dist` directory because I am using Babel to transpile, so this is where my tests are being run. I am transpiling to the current Node version, but I have tried transpiling to older versions with no luck and the same errors.

The file generating the error is `./users.test.js`:

```
import request from "supertest";
import app from "../../app";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

describe("users", () => {
   let mongoServer;
   beforeAll(async () => {
      mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
      await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri(), { dbName: "verifyMASTER" });
   });

   afterAll(async () => {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
   });

   describe("Register and Login new user", () => {
      let user = {
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Doe",
         email: `${uuid()}@email.com`,
         password: `${uuid()}`,
      };

      const fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "token"];

      test("New user should be registered and password should be encrypted", async () => {
         return await request(app)
            .post("/auth/register")
            .send(user)
            .expect(201)
            .expect("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .expect((res) => {
               // check response for required fields
               for (const field in fields) {
                  if (!res.body.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                     return false;
                  }
               }
               // check if password has been saved correctly
               return bcrypt.compare(user.password, res.body.password); // returns true or false;
            })
            .toBeTruthy();
      });
   });
});
```

The relevant dependencies I am using are:

```
@babel/cli@7.17.10 
@babel/core@7.17.10
@babel/preset-env@7.17.10 
babel-jest@28.1.0 
jest@27.5.1
mongodb-memory-server@8.5.2
mongoose@6.3.0
superagent@7.1.2
supertest@6.2.2
```

I am using a combination of mongodb-memory-server and supertest to recreate the effects of going through my application and interacting with mongoDB.

I've been researching and I think the issue has to do with either my configuration of Babel/Jest to get them to work together or perhaps I am not importing something to my file to have these functions recognized.

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageReporters: ["json", "text", "lcov", "clover", "cobertura"],
  rootDir: "dist"
}
```

Comment: Supertest's `.expect` method is **not** Jest's `expect` function. They have the same name, and similar purposes, but they aren't the same - `.expect` returns an object with the Supertest methods for chaining, `expect` returns an object with the matchers for asserting.

Comment: You are using `request.expect` from `supertest` not `expect` from `jest`